# WordPress subtle theme Search is broken

Tags: wordpress

I know this isn't probably exactly programming related, but I'm building a website on the famous Subtle theme and realized that even on it's demo the search page is broken so if i could get an answer to this it would mean a lot to me and to other's using that theme.

I have the website on the aadress http://work.askonomm.com/rs, please do use search and if you can figure out why it does what it does i would really appreciate it.

Comment: had a quick look at the URL on my iPhone and it seems the page has gone all the way to the right. is this the "broken" issue you're referring to?

Comment: had a quick look at the URL on my iPhone and it seems the page has gone all the way to the right. is this the "broken" issue you're referring to? if so you might want to cross reference the searchform.php file and the CSS stylesheet to see if any of the applied styles are causing this.

Answer (score 2):

The `search` class in the CSS currently has `float:right` and `width:170px;` set.

This is causing at least part of the problem you're seeing. Removing these items brings the page back in to view and positioned centrally.